# Producing nonlinear function to be optimized in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am attempting to minimize this nonlinear function

[image]

using the BFGS optimization method in MATLAB. However, I am having a terrible time figuring out how to code the function for n=500. I have tried these variations with no luck:

1)
`S_symsum = @(x) (100*(x(2*(1:250))-x(2*(1:250)-1)^2)^2+(1-x(2*(1:250)-1))^2);`

2)
`k = 1:N/2;
V = (100*(x(2*k)-x(2*k-1).^2).^2+(1-x(2*k-1)).^2); 
f = sum(V);`

3)`f = symsum(100*(x(2*k)-x(2*k-1).^2).^2+(1-x(2*k-1)).^2,k,1,500)`

EDIT: As the BFGS method necessitates, I will need to be able to take the gradient of the function f at each iterate. So, the function formulation will need to hold this property

Comment: `f = @(x) sum(100*(x(2:2:end)-x(1:2:end).^2).^2+(1-x(2:2:end)).^2)`?

Comment: how does it know to sum from 1 to 500 (n = 500)?

Comment: This function is minimized for a vector `x` with all elements equal to 1 (where you get `F(x)==0`).

Comment: @user23985723985 it doesn't. It will do it until the last value of  `x`. so if `x` has `n=500` values (`length(x)==500`) then it will do 500, if it has 20 then it will do 20.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, that is intuitive, but the starting vector will be of zeros and I'm not guaranteed to find the global optimum of the function given its unique properties

Comment: @David would I be able to take the gradient of this function?

Comment: @user23985723985 you can't have gradient of function handle, the gradient function is made only for `syms` function

Answer (score 0):

I use N = 10 for illustration, just change it to 500 for your optimization.

```
% given length of x, here N
N = 10;
% supposed x is a row vector 
 x = sym('x', [1,N]);
f = 0;
 for i = 1:N/2
    f =   f + 100.*(x(2*i) - (x(2*i-1)).^2) + (1-x(2*i-1)).^2;
 end


% gradient 
% to compute gradient, use syms function type
g = gradient(f);


% for evaluating the function or the gradient use function handle
feval = matlabFunction(f, 'vars', {x});
geval = matlabFunction(g, 'vars', {x});
```

Comment: please do not overwrite the function name `sum`. It exists in matlab. Call it `mysum` or something else.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will be performing BFGS as the nonlinear optimization method. Thus, at each iterate I will need to be able to get the gradient of the function f. Is this possible with this formulation?

Comment: @CrisLuengo 1)Agree with N being even, 2) the use of `fmincon` is rather to show OP can use any optimizer that need function handle. 3) `syms` function can be differenciated, function handle can't

Comment: @Adam Thank you kindly! I will be looking further into this later

Comment: @user23985723985 kindly accept the answer if you think that helps you. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Adam I will do that as soon as I get the chance to verify that I can use this formulation